# When Ever i make user to signup through firebase he is authenticate but data is not written in firebase db?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When ever i make a user to signup and he is authenticate by firebase but the data is not saving in firebase db and give below error message. Is there a way to controll this error?

Error Message:

```
   A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations
```

[Error Message Alert image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4lKo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the rules of firebase database.
If not checked then please update the read & write permission.
Like given below

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: the write rule is this


    `".write": "auth != null",`

does it effect it?

Comment: Yaa it will definitely effect.. just try rules as I typed.